# Html/static files to React Componet /stateless functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components, react-router

I am moving a portfolio from Html with bootstrap and vanilla js to **React**. I am successful in most part since most of it is writing html and bootstrap in jsx which seems to have no issue so far. But  i am running into a problem with specific set of html and js codes that has to do with chart display . I am trying to make these set of codes into a component like I did it with others. i am getting this error **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null"**. I try to do componentdid mount will mount , then i get the chart itself is not defined error.  Below is the html and inline js code that work with no problem and  my Stateless function attempt. the **chart data** itself is from https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/LICENSE.md  .  if any one want to see the entire code , its here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/552xpfs3ubggrmd/portfolio.rar?dl=0  ps: Testing.html have the entire code, these are the codes I am trying to make it into a component

```js
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
import chart from '../../../assets/js/Chart';
import '../../../assets/css/main.css';

export default class Skills extends Component {


render() {
  var doughnutData1 = [
        {
          value: 55,
          color:"#1abc9c"
        },
        {
          value : 30,
          color : "#ecf0f1"
        }
      ];
  var doughnutData2 = [
          {
            value: 80,
            color:"#1abc9c"
          },
          {
            value : 10,
            color : "#ecf0f1"
          }
        ];
  var doughnutData3 = [
            {
              value: 40,
              color:"#1abc9c"
            },
            {
              value : 35,
              color : "#ecf0f1"
            }
          ];
  var doughnutData4 = [
              {
                value: 95,
                color:"#1abc9c"
              },
              {
                value : 20,
                color : "#ecf0f1"
              }
            ];
  var doughnutData5 = [
                {
                  value: 65,
                  color:"#1abc9c"
                },
                {
                  value : 30,
                  color : "#ecf0f1"
                }
              ];
  var doughnutData6 = [
                  {
                    value: 50,
                    color:"#1abc9c"
                  },
                  {
                    value : 50,
                    color : "#ecf0f1"
                  }
                ];

      let myDoughnut1 = new chart.Chart(document.getElementById("javascript").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData1);
      let myDoughnut2 = new chart.Chart(document.getElementById("bootstrap").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData2);
      let myDoughnut3 = new chart.Chart(document.getElementById("wordpress").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData3);
      let myDoughnut4 = new chart.Chart(document.getElementById("html").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData4);
      let myDoughnut5 = new chart.Chart(document.getElementById("photoshop").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData5);
      let myDoughnut6 = new chart.Chart(document.getElementById("illustrator").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData6);

////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////



return (

//start
<div>


  <div id="skillswrap">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1">
            <h5>SKILLS</h5>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-3 centered">
            <canvas id="javascript" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
            <p>Javascript</p>
            <br></br>
             {myDoughnut1}
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-3 centered">
            <canvas id="bootstrap" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
            <p>Bootstrap</p>
            <br></br>
               {myDoughnut2}
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-3 centered">
            <canvas id="wordpress" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
            <p>jQuery</p>
            <br></br>
               {myDoughnut3}
          </div>

          <div className="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3 centered">
            <canvas id="html" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
            <p>HTML/CSS</p>
            <br></br>
               {myDoughnut4}
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-3 centered">
            <canvas id="photoshop" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
            <p>Angular Js</p>
            <br></br>
               {myDoughnut5}
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-3 centered">
            <canvas id="illustrator" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
            <p>React</p>
            <br></br>
               {myDoughnut6}
          </div>
  <p>Other Skills - UNIX Commands, NPM, Gulp, bower packages, Web packs </p>
  <p>Other Soft Skills - NOSQL,MYSQL, Node JS </p>
  <p>Other Softer Skills - C#, Java, Objective C, MYSQL, PHP, Python </p>


      </div>
  <br></br>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
//end


);




};





}
```

```html
<div id="skillswrap">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1">
      <h5>SKILLS</h5>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
      <canvas id="javascript" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
      <p>Javascript</p>
      <br>
      <script>
       var doughnutData = [
         {
          value: 55,
          color:"#1abc9c"
         },
         {
          value : 30,
          color : "#ecf0f1"
         }
        ];
        var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("javascript").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
      </script>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
      <canvas id="bootstrap" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
      <p>Bootstrap</p>
      <br>
      <script>
       var doughnutData = [
         {
          value: 80,
          color:"#1abc9c"
         },
         {
          value : 10,
          color : "#ecf0f1"
         }
        ];
        var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("bootstrap").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
      </script>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
      <canvas id="wordpress" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
      <p>jQuery</p>
      <br>
      <script>
       var doughnutData = [
         {
          value: 40,
          color:"#1abc9c"
         },
         {
          value : 35,
          color : "#ecf0f1"
         }
        ];
        var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("wordpress").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
      </script>
     </div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3 centered">
      <canvas id="html" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
      <p>HTML/CSS</p>
      <br>
      <script>
       var doughnutData = [
         {
          value: 95,
          color:"#1abc9c"
         },
         {
          value : 20,
          color : "#ecf0f1"
         }
        ];
        var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("html").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
      </script>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
      <canvas id="photoshop" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
      <p>Angular Js</p>
      <br>
      <script>
       var doughnutData = [
         {
          value: 65,
          color:"#1abc9c"
         },
         {
          value : 30,
          color : "#ecf0f1"
         }
        ];
        var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("photoshop").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
      </script>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
      <canvas id="illustrator" height="130" width="130"></canvas>
      <p>React</p>
      <br>
      <script>
       var doughnutData = [
         {
          value: 50,
          color:"#1abc9c"
         },
         {
          value : 50,
          color : "#ecf0f1"
         }
        ];
        var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("illustrator").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
      </script>
     </div>
<p>Other Skills - UNIX Commands, NPM, Gulp, bower packages, Web packs </p>
<p>Other Soft Skills - NOSQL,MYSQL, Node JS </p>
<p>Other Softer Skills - C#, Java, Objective C, MYSQL, PHP, Python </p>


   </div>
   <br>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `document.getElementById("...").getContext("2d")` failing in `render()` because element was not mounted to DOM yet.

You should wait `componentDidMount` and init your Chart module there.

Rough example:

```
 export default class Skills extends Component {

      componentDidMount() {
           new chart.Chart(this.javascriptEl.getContext("2d")).Doughnut(data);
      }

      render() {
          return (
               <canvas ref={(el) => {this.javascriptEl=el}}></canvas>
          );
      }
 }
```